# Python process starts but does not actually run the target function

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm using multiprocessing to test proxy server usability. The target function of my process takes a proxy server address and a queue as arguments and opens an instance of webdriver with the given proxy. The function tests the proxy by going to a specific url and trying to retrieve an html element. If the test is successful the function will add the webdriver instance to the queue. The function is shown below.

```
def test_proxy(address, queue):
        print(f"testing proxy {address}")
        chrome_options_1 = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options_1.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % address)
        chrome_options_1.add_argument("headless")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('.\driver\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options_1)
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)
        url = "https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/nyc/search/?query=honda"
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class='kbiprv82']/a").get_attribute("href")
            print(f"Successfully connected to proxy server at {address}")
            queue.put(driver)
            return
        except:
            print("Connection failed")
        driver.quit()
```

In my main process I have a list of proxy addresses to test. A process is created to test each proxy in the list until a test is successful and a driver instance is put in the queue. If an item is found in the queue all the processes are terminated and the proxy list is cleared. The loop in my main process limits the number of child processes to 10. The main process code is in a class and shown below.

```
def find_proxy(self):
        self.proxies = []
        self.proxy_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
        
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        chrome_options.add_argument("headless")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('.\driver\chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
        driver.get("https://free-proxy-list.net/")

        Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tfoot/tr/th[7]/select")).select_by_visible_text("yes")

        for country in ["US", "MX", "CA", "CL", "CO", "BR", "PE"]:
            try:
                Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='proxylisttable']/tfoot/tr/th[3]/select")).select_by_visible_text(country)
                i = 0
                entries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[@id='proxylisttable']/tbody/tr/td")
                for entry in entries:
                    if i == 7:
                        i = 0
                        self.proxies.append([proxy_address])
                    else:
                        if i == 0:
                            proxy_address = entry.text + ':'
                        if i == 1:
                            proxy_address = proxy_address + entry.text
                        i = i + 1
            except:
                pass

        driver.quit()

        while len(self.proxies) > 0:
            i = 0
            for proxy in self.proxies[:10]:
                if self.proxy_queue.empty() == False:
                    driver = self.proxy_queue.get()
                    for proxy_1 in self.proxies:
                        try:
                            proxy_1[1].terminate()
                        except:
                            pass
                    self.proxies.clear()
                    return driver
                elif len(proxy) < 2:
                    proxy.insert(1, multiprocessing.Process(target=test_proxy, args=(proxy[0], self.proxy_queue,)))
                    print(f"proxy thread {proxy[0]} created")
                    proxy[1].start()
                    print(f"proxy thread {proxy[0]} started")
                elif proxy[1].is_alive() == False:
                    print(f"proxy thread {proxy[0]} dead")
                    del self.proxies[i]
                    print("proxy deleted")
                    break
                i = i + 1
```

The issue is that the processes seem to start just fine but none of the code in the test_proxy function is actually run, not even the first print statement.

Comment: I didn't include the code to populate the proxy list but I'll add that to make it more clear

Comment: How are you running this?  Remember that your `test_proxy` code is going to run in a completely separate process, with a separate Python interpreter.  If you're running at a command line, you should the output on stdout, but from an IDE not so much.  Also, you're trying to return the Selenium driver object through the queue; I'm not sure that's going to work.

Comment: I'm running it with idle. I'm a little confused what you're saying about stdout. I'm not too worried about returning the driver through the queue, if that doesn't work I'll just return the address instead.